# jQuery function does not fire on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function written in jQuery. it works fine. The only problem the function does not fire on first  click. any solve or idea?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.swipe-prev').on('click', function() {


    var prevImg = $('img.active').prev('.result-image-act img');
    if (prevImg.length == 0) {
      prevImg = $('.result-image-act img:last');
    }
    $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    prevImg.addClass('active');
  });

  $('.swipe-next').on('click', function() {
    var nextImg = $('img.active').next('.result-image-act img');
    if (nextImg.length == 0) {
      nextImg = $('.result-image-act img:first');
    }
    $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    nextImg.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.result-row {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 290px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 290px;
  margin: 4px 0 12px 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.result-image-act {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.result-image-act img {
  display: none;
}

.result-image-act .active {
  display: block;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.embed-result-price {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  color: #111;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* swipe styling */

.swipe-wrap-lef {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 87px;
  left: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.swipe-wrap-rig {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 87px;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.swipe-wrap-next {}

.swipe-wrap a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.swipe-prev {
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  /* as the half of the width */
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swipe-next {
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  /* as the half of the width */
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swipe-prev:hover,
.swipe-next:hover {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}

.swipe-prev p,
.swipe-next p {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="result-row">
  <!-- image box -->

  <a href="#">
    <div class="result-image-act">
      <img src="1.jpg" alt="image 1" class="active">
      <img src="2.jpg" alt="image 2">
      <img src="3.jpg" alt="image 3">
      <img src="4.jpg" alt="image 4">
      <img src="5.jpg" alt="image 5">
      <img src="6.jpg" alt="image 6">
      <img src="7.jpg" alt="image 7">
      <img src="8.jpg" alt="image 8">
      <img src="9.jpg" alt="image 9">
      <img src="10.jpg" alt="image 10">
    </div>
    <span class="embed-result-price">36.0</span>
    <div class="swipe-wrap">
      <div class="swipe-wrap-lef">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="swipe-prev">
            <p>&lt;</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="swipe-wrap-rig">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="swipe-next">
            <p>&gt;</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <p class="result-info">
    <span style="color:#ccc" title=""> &#9734; </span>
    <time class="result-date" datetime="2018-03-05 8:36" title="Mon 05 
        Mar 08:36:12 PM"> Mar 5</time>
    <a href="#" data-id="" class="result-title"> T shirt </a>
    <span class="result-price">36.0</span>
    <span class="post-hide"><i class="fa fa-trash trash-can" aria-
        hidden="true"></i> </span>
  </p>
</li>
```

Comment: Delete $(document).ready(function() as you want it to be triggered on click, not when document is ready.

Comment: @JoelBonetR How what that help

Comment: Running the code snippet here seems to work fine, can you explain a bit better when it fails?

Comment: i explained both questions in my answer @CarstenLøvboAndersen
  it runs fine here because document ready occurs inmediatelly after pressing "run code snippet".

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('.swipe-prev').click(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `z-index: 20;` to `swipe-next` and `swipe-prev`

Because if you inspect your html, you can see that the images is "ontop" of the container for the `< >`

**demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.swipe-prev').on('click', function() {


    var prevImg = $('img.active').prev('.result-image-act img');
    if (prevImg.length == 0) {
      prevImg = $('.result-image-act img:last');
    }
    $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    prevImg.addClass('active');
  });

  $('.swipe-next').on('click', function() {
    var nextImg = $('img.active').next('.result-image-act img');
    if (nextImg.length == 0) {
      nextImg = $('.result-image-act img:first');
    }
    $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    nextImg.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.result-row {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 290px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 290px;
  margin: 4px 0 12px 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.result-image-act {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.result-image-act img {
  display: none;
}

.result-image-act .active {
  display: block;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.embed-result-price {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  color: #111;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* swipe styling */

.swipe-wrap-lef {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 87px;
  left: 0px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 20;
}

.swipe-wrap-rig {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 87px;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 20;
}

.swipe-wrap-next {}

.swipe-wrap a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.swipe-prev {
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  /* as the half of the width */
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swipe-next {
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  /* as the half of the width */
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swipe-prev:hover,
.swipe-next:hover {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}

.swipe-prev p,
.swipe-next p {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="result-row">
  <!-- image box -->

  <a href="#">
    <div class="result-image-act">
      <img src="https://hunyadi.info.hu/levente/images/stories/boxplus/image3.jpg" alt="1" class="active">
      <img src="2.jpg" alt="2">
      <img src="https://hunyadi.info.hu/levente/images/stories/boxplus/image3.jpg" alt="3">
      <img src="4.jpg" alt="4">
      <img src="https://hunyadi.info.hu/levente/images/stories/boxplus/image3.jpg" alt="5">
      <img src="6.jpg" alt="6">
      <img src="https://hunyadi.info.hu/levente/images/stories/boxplus/image3.jpg" alt="7">
      <img src="8.jpg" alt="8">
      <img src="https://hunyadi.info.hu/levente/images/stories/boxplus/image3.jpg" alt="9">
      <img src="10.jpg" alt="10">
    </div>
    <span class="embed-result-price">36.0</span>
    <div class="swipe-wrap">
      <div class="swipe-wrap-lef">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="swipe-prev">
            <p>&lt;</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="swipe-wrap-rig">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="swipe-next">
            <p>&gt;</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <p class="result-info">
    <span style="color:#ccc" title=""> &#9734; </span>
    <time class="result-date" datetime="2018-03-05 8:36" title="Mon 05 
        Mar 08:36:12 PM"> Mar 5</time>
    <a href="#" data-id="" class="result-title"> T shirt </a>
    <span class="result-price">36.0</span>
    <span class="post-hide"><i class="fa fa-trash trash-can" aria-
        hidden="true"></i> </span>
  </p>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Few Things:

First of all please remove the "$(document).ready(function() {}" as your event is working on click, so no need to add OnReady function there.

Second, I tried your code it works just perfect, the only problem could be the Image rendering, it might takes some time to render that's why you are assuming that it is not working for the first time.

Try to print something in the console for each click and you will get to know whether it works or not. Just as I did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.swipe-prev').on('click', function() {
        console.log("Prev");    // Print "Prev" on click swipe-prev
        var prevImg = $('img.active').prev('.result-image-act img');
        if (prevImg.length == 0) {
          prevImg = $('.result-image-act img:last');
        }
        $('img.active').removeClass('active');
        prevImg.addClass('active');
    });

    $('.swipe-next').on('click', function() {
        console.log("Next");  // Print "Next" on click swipe-next
        var nextImg = $('img.active').next('.result-image-act img');
        if (nextImg.length == 0) {
          nextImg = $('.result-image-act img:first');
        }
        $('img.active').removeClass('active');
        nextImg.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i told you in a comment, you want this function being triggered when click event occurs, and you are telling jQuery eventlistener to watch for document ready (event ready only occurs one time, when the document is loaded fully).
It's working anyway but on the first click the document may not being loaded at all for you, maybe a lazy load on images etc.
Just remove this event listener to trigger your function, no need to concat both event listeners, as you only need one.

Think, for example that i've slow internet conenction and i see the first image when the document is still loading, why i shouldn't be able to click to see next image? I've to wait till document loads at all to see the next one?

there's no sense with it.

Its working to me as is:

```js
  $('.swipe-prev').on('click', function() {
    var prevImg = $('img.active').prev('.result-image-act img');
    if (prevImg.length == 0) {
      prevImg = $('.result-image-act img:last');
    }
    $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    prevImg.addClass('active');
  });

  $('.swipe-next').on('click', function() {
    var nextImg = $('img.active').next('.result-image-act img');
    if (nextImg.length == 0) {
      nextImg = $('.result-image-act img:first');
    }
    $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    nextImg.addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.result-row {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 290px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 290px;
  margin: 4px 0 12px 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.result-image-act {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.result-image-act img {
  display: none;
}

.result-image-act .active {
  display: block;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.embed-result-price {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  color: #111;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* swipe styling */

.swipe-wrap-lef {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 87px;
  left: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.swipe-wrap-rig {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 87px;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.swipe-wrap-next {}

.swipe-wrap a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.swipe-prev {
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  /* as the half of the width */
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swipe-next {
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  /* as the half of the width */
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swipe-prev:hover,
.swipe-next:hover {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}

.swipe-prev p,
.swipe-next p {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="result-row">
  <!-- image box -->

  <a href="#">
    <div class="result-image-act">
      <img src="1.jpg" alt="image 1" class="active">
      <img src="2.jpg" alt="image 2">
      <img src="3.jpg" alt="image 3">
      <img src="4.jpg" alt="image 4">
      <img src="5.jpg" alt="image 5">
      <img src="6.jpg" alt="image 6">
      <img src="7.jpg" alt="image 7">
      <img src="8.jpg" alt="image 8">
      <img src="9.jpg" alt="image 9">
      <img src="10.jpg" alt="image 10">
    </div>
    <span class="embed-result-price">36.0</span>
    <div class="swipe-wrap">
      <div class="swipe-wrap-lef">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="swipe-prev">
            <p>&lt;</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="swipe-wrap-rig">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="swipe-next">
            <p>&gt;</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <p class="result-info">
    <span style="color:#ccc" title=""> &#9734; </span>
    <time class="result-date" datetime="2018-03-05 8:36" title="Mon 05 
        Mar 08:36:12 PM"> Mar 5</time>
    <a href="#" data-id="" class="result-title"> T shirt </a>
    <span class="result-price">36.0</span>
    <span class="post-hide"><i class="fa fa-trash trash-can" aria-
        hidden="true"></i> </span>
  </p>
</li>
```